# Trying to automate to click on Search button in Selenium Python module, but it is not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need help to automate to click the search button in this webpage. The code works so far, until I reach the search button.
Below are the elements for this button. The value named Search is unique for this button.

```html
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="submitfilter();">
```

Below is the code:

```
from selenium  import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
url = "http://fake.com"
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
    
ABC = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//input[@value="Search"]"))
ABC.click()
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: BC = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//input[@value='Search']"))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntactical error on that line, you're using double quotes for the Xpath and so for the value inside it, which makes the code treat search as a variable.

Change the line to:

```
ABC = driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//input[@value="Search"]'))
```

Comment: This didnt work unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please share the error and webpage if possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
ABC = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@value='Search']")
```

The proper way to write this would be like so. Not calling the By.xpath with the string of the xpat.